# Framed content doesn't render properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, frames

Here is my issue :)

Check out the two following sites **on IE 9**, or on a smartphone:

- [link disabled]
- [link disabled]

As you can see, the second website does not work properly (background, buttons and js do not work, etc.). The code behind both is exactly the same (using bootstrap, jquery, etc.), with one difference: for some reason I need a nice URL and cannot change my host (villice.be), which is why I asked ovh to re-direct eneco.creo2.org to the first URL (villice.be/...).

When I look at what OVH is doing, they wrap my documents by adding a frame and frameset in this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="keywords" content="">
            <meta name="generator" content="ORT - Ovh Redirect Technology">
            <meta name="url" content="http://villice.be/creo2/eneco/www">
            <meta name="robots" content="all">
        </head>
        <frameset rows="100%,0" frameborder=no border=0>
            <frame name="ORT" src="http://villice.be/creo2/eneco/www">
            <frame name="NONE" src="" scrolling="no" noresize>
            <noframes>
                <body><a href="http://villice.be/creo2/eneco/www">Click here</a><hr></body>
            </noframes>
        </frameset>
    </html>
```

I guess this frame is the cause of the following bad displays:

- On desktop: works fine with Chrome, but not with IE 9. The troubles seems to be: part of the javascript is unloaded, css unloaded (?)(e.g., background-image:cover does not work), etc...
- On smartphone: no responsiveness (smartphone seems to think he is a desktop), even on chrome
- potentially other display errors

Is there a workaround around this, knowing that I do not control the code ovh is adding? Maybe I can try to change it with jQuery after the document is loaded?

Any input is welcome :)

Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you need more info to solve this problem! Looking forward to read you guys ;-)

Comment: Both sites appear to work fine in IE11 on Win7/64.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The issue is actually on IE9. And on any smartphone you will see that there is no responsiveness any more.